# Setting a dependency property of a control in the custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a infragistics grid that i have inherited from in the my solution . Now i would like to set a dependency property defined in the infragistics grid control in my custom control code behind and not in xaml . How do i accomplish setting the dependency property ?

I was able to set the backing CLR property in my custom control but as expected it didnt trigger off the gridcontrol UI change as expected and hence i m forced to set the dependency property in my custom control .

How exactly do i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a `DependencyProperty` is declared like this with CLR property 'wrappers':

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(YourControlType));

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

If the `Grid` that you inherited declared their `DependencyProperties` like this, then you should be able to use the CLR wrapped properties directly like this:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Items.Add("Something");
```

If they didn't do that, then you can see in the wrapped properties how to access them:

```
anInstanceOfYourControlType.SetValue(ItemsProperty, "some value");
```

There is of course a chance that they declared internal properties in which case you won't be able to access them, but you should be able to find that out from their online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DependencyProperty [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set local value of Dependency Property.

```
dataGridObject.SetValue(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, value);
```

But in case your DP binded with some CLR property and you want to update it as well, use [SetCurrentValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
dataGridObject.SetCurrentValue(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, value);
```